# Hyperlink in Gridview which is autogenerated in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Gridview which is autogenerated by fetching data from various tables.
Now my requirement is i need to make my first column as hyperlink so that if it is clicked then it has to navigate to another page with hyperlinked value.
In the second page i have Lable this label should show the hyperlink value and based on that the data will be populated on the second page.

For example:
I have a gridview with 10 columns..My first column is Emp Id.
If that id is clicked it has to take me to second page and the label control must get this id value and based on that id the rest of the info like emp name emp DOB should be filled.
i am using C# as my code behind.

Can anyone help me to proceed..
Awaiting ur reply

Answer (score 3):

You need the `<asp:HyperLinkField />`

```
<asp:GridView>
<Columns>
   <asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText="Id" DataTextField="YourID" DataNavigateUrlFields="YourID" 
           DataNavigateUrlFormatString="SecondPage.aspx?Id={0}" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

You might need to remove the `AutoGenerateColumns="true"` property and type the fields yourself, selecting only the columns you want to show - using `<asp:BoundFied DataField="ColumnName" />`

In case you want to pass multiple values in the querystring, separate the fields with comma

```
 DataNavigateUrlFields="YourID, SecondField"
```

and your format string would be

```
DataNavigateUrlFormatString="SecondPage.aspx?Id={0}&param2={1}"
```

Other links

- [HyperLinkField.DataNavigateUrlFormatString Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlinkfield.datanavigateurlformatstring.aspx)
- [How to pass multiple values in HyperlinkField](http://abhijitjana.net/2010/07/27/how-to-pass-multiple-values-using-gridview-hyperlinkfield/)

Comment: I know that i can use HyperLink field and for that i have to make  AutoGenerateColumns="false". My requirement is i have to fetch data from various tables and thn i am filling the gridview. In this case is it possible to make AutoGenerateColumns="false" and use Hyperlinkfield property.

Comment: Yes. You just have to specify all the columns you want in the gridview manually. `AutoGenerateColumns="false"` does not affect where fields are coming from, it's just telling the gridview whether to show all columns retrieved or [wait], I want to populate them myself. All the columns are still available for you regardless of that property.

Comment: Harae yaar..    I think i didnt explain u correctly.. Initially i have to fill my gridview by fetching data from various Database tables.. once the gridview is populated with the data then i have to make first  column of mu gridview as hyperlink to second page by passing only one value (i.e. ID)

Comment: Just try it out. Your gridview needs not know how or where data came from. It could be SqlDataSource, ObjectDataSource or from ADO.Net code. Those determine where the values were picked from. Remove autogenerate columns property or even leave it and include the link as specified in the answer. You will have extra column with the autogenerated columns. That's all

Comment: i hav 1 column field of my gridview which is not fetched from table rather based on the condition im filling it.            if(Createdby!= Allocatedcode)
            {
                SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("select co_name from company_master where co_code='" + Allocatedcode + "'", con);
                Allocatedname = Convert.ToString(cmd2.ExecuteScalar());
            }
 else
      {
           Allocatedname = Createdname;
       }                                                 Allocatedname is that field.so in this situation is it possible to go with ur suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `TemplateField` column in your GridView:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink ID="linkToDetails" runat="server" NavigateUrl='Details.aspx?empId=<%# Eval("empId") %>' Text='<%# Eval("empId") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

On the Details.aspx page you should get the empId from the QueryString and get the details from the database.

Comment: I know that i can use Template field and for that i have to make AutoGenerateColumns="false". My requirement is i have to fetch data from various tables and then i am filling the gridview. In this case is it possible to make AutoGenerateColumns="false" and use TemplateField property.

Comment: Why would you want to enable `AutoGenerateColumns`?